# issue with adding custom button to the toolbar of tinymce vue.js wrapper

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, tinymce

i am trying to adding custom button to the toolbar of tinymce using the vue.js wrapper(using vue 3 and tinymce 5)
the issue that the custom button doesn't show in the toolbar

i have tried the following , the logs in the init and setup are showing in the console and when using
`tinymce.activeEditor.ui.registry.getAll().buttons` i am able to see the test button there

```
<template>
  <Editor
    api-key="any-key"
    v-model="content"
    :init="editorSettings"
    @onInit="handleEditorInit"
  />
</template>

<script>
import Editor from '@tinymce/tinymce-vue';

export default {
  components: {
    Editor,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      content: '',
      editorSettings: {
        setup: function (editor) {
          console.log('setup', editor);
          editor.on('init', function () {
            console.log('setup init', editor);
            editor.ui.registry.addButton('test', {
              text: 'Custom',
              tooltip: 'Add Custom Action',
              onAction: function () {
                console.log('test button clicked');
              },
            });
          });
        },
        toolbar: 'test',
      },
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

i have came across this method  `editor.ui.registry.addToToolbar('customAction');` to add the button manually but it doesn't really exist in the registry object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of registering the button within the `init` event, you should register it directly within the `setup` method. This ensures that the button is registered before the toolbar is rendered.

```js
<template>
  <Editor
    api-key="any-key"
    v-model="content"
    :init="editorSettings"
    @onInit="handleEditorInit"
  />
</template>

<script>
import Editor from '@tinymce/tinymce-vue';

export default {
  components: {
    Editor,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      content: '',
      editorSettings: {
        setup: function (editor) {
          console.log('setup', editor);

          // Register the custom button directly within the setup method
          editor.ui.registry.addButton('test', {
            text: 'Custom',
            tooltip: 'Add Custom Action',
            onAction: function () {
              console.log('test button clicked');
            },
          });

          editor.on('init', function () {
            console.log('setup init', editor);
          });
        },
        toolbar: 'test',
      },
    };
  },
  methods: {
    handleEditorInit() {
      console.log('Editor initialized');
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

By moving the `addButton` call outside of the `init` event and directly into the `setup` method, the custom button should now appear in the toolbar as expected.